# NetSuite or SuiteScript filter vendor in sublist by item

Tags: netsuite, suitescript

I had a request from a client to restrict the vendor list in the item sublist on transaction records such as quotes, sales orders, etc. I have tried sourcing but have not found anything, but I could have missed it. Whether by UI or with script does anyone have any ideas as to how to do this? Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a line field Vendor and you would like to restrict the list of available values to display, for example only vendors from China, you will need to go to the field definition and under Sourcing & Filtering tab select filtering criteria as on the screenshot below

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Hi and thanks, I am using a custom field and it doesn't offer the ability to filter by item.